# not able to access next element while looping through the array and using [current_element + 1] in vue?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuex

```
<div
              v-for="(element, index) in getElements"
              :key="index>
    {{element[index].natural_element}} {{element[index+1].natural_element}}
```

I am get an array of object from getelement (vuex is being used for state management).
what I was trying to do is get current as well as next element in for loop but I am not able to do that, why is it so? how should I do it?
this is also something I tried.

```
<div
             v-for="(element, index) in getElements"
             :key="index>
   {{getElements[index].natural_element}} {{getElements[index+1].natural_element}}
```

error I am getting: natural_element is undefined.(when I dont use index+1, I get no error)

below is the array I am getting from api call:

```
[{
  "natural_element":123,
  "non-natural_element": 23
 },
{
  "natural_element":23,
  "non-natural_element": 123
}]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure index should be the first element of the destructuring. (index, element) in getElements

Comment: Hi @Trent  I already tried, this didn't work and this is not the correct too.